# Proof of residue theorem (residue formula) for differential forms on curves over an arbitrary closed field.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces, differential-forms, residue-calculus

I have been reading the book [Algebraic Geometric Codes: Basic Notions](http://www.math.umass.edu/%7Ehajir/m499c/tvn-book.pdf) by Tsfasman, Vladut and Nogin. They give a residue formula like this (Proposition 2.2.20, p. 97):

Let $\mathbb{k}$ be an algebraically closed field and $X$ be a smooth projective curve over $\mathbb{k}$. Let $\omega$ be a rational differential form on $X$. Then,

$\displaystyle\sum_{P \in X}^{} Res_P(\omega) = 0$

Here $P$ denotes the points on the curve $X$ and $Res_P(\omega)$ denotes the residues of $\omega$ at points $P$.

I know that this can easily be derived with the help of Green's/Stoke's theorems in case where $\mathbb{k} = \mathbb{C}$ , as $X$ will then have the natural structure of a Riemann surface and things like integrals will start making sense. But, I am unable to prove it for an arbitrary algebraically closed field $\mathbb{k}$ other than $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: You're right that this is not obvious. It is a major theorem. The two main approaches are by Serre: *Groupes algebriques et corps de classes* chapter 2, or Tate: *Residues of differentials on curves* (can be found on Numdam).

Comment: @Matt I guess that's what I am looking for; Thanks.

Comment: One should say that Serre's proof is written for classical varieties (hence, over an algebraically closed field), whereas Tate's one works over any ground field (algebraically closed or not).